# Should we merge a beta stage proposal into a general one or widen its scope instead?

Tags: discussion, area-51

If the community behind wordpress answers support a change to widen its scope, would it be possible to merge all CMS proposals into it?

cf: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/cms-blog-proposals-merger

old question: <strike>Can you vote to close/merge a proposal in commit phase?</strike> ([just found out it's possible](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5744/star-trek))

Answer (score 1):

*IF* a consensus is reached, it's a simple matter to contact the followers of a proposal to ask them to support another proposal or integrate their support into a site. A site can expand it's scope through meta discussions and updating its FAQ.

Deciding whether it is best to let proposals compete, or to join forces and support a united proposal, or to integrate their ideas into an expanded site *sometimes* takes time and careful consideration. A very, very small percentage of the followers participate in these merge discussions, and a percentage of *them* aren't directly involved in the communities they are advising.

Comment: the underlying question is whether we should plan ahead to merge down/up with wordpress answers or if we should take the path of *nix (renouncing ubuntu inclusion)?