# Are communities ever merged? If so, what is the process?

Tags: discussion, community

I was surprised to see we have separate communities for bitcoin, ethereum and perhaps other individual cryptocurrencies, and no overarching cryptocurrency site (we have cryptography but not quite the same) If we take SO as an analogy isn't that like having separate C++, C#, Java, JS communities? And SO is *huge* but I don't see proposals to split it up.

It's just one example but I have no idea how or indeed where one might suggest this sort of thing. Do individual communities have full control so they would have to agree to merge or does SE have control over this sort of thing?

Hypothetically, what *would* be the way this happens in the SE ecosystem? Create a new community which subsumes several existing ones and see if the old ones wither with people migrating seems pragmatic but somewhat cynical.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [Any successful mergers of Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354766/295232)

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364292/should-we-reconsider-the-requirements-for-making-new-cryptocurrency-sites

Comment: Splitting up [SO] has been proposed many times https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252781/would-it-be-a-terrible-idea-to-split-so-up-into-a-tiered-platform

Comment: As an example, my question doesn't seem to have a home... it' not about one currency. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89965/90320

Comment: @PaulWhite that suggests splitting by reputation/level not by topic though? But all these ultra-focused sites seem a bit odd. Shame they're not "under one roof" IMO.

Comment: [This seems relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78477/should-we-merge-a-beta-stage-proposal-into-a-general-one-or-widen-its-scope-inst) though I suspect that things might have changed a lot since then

Comment: Some relevant discussion happened recently on [an answer to "*Should we reconsider the requirements for making new cryptocurrency sites?*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364292/should-we-reconsider-the-requirements-for-making-new-cryptocurrency-sites/364294#364294).

Comment: Worth adding that it sounds like an intensive process: in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364292/should-we-reconsider-the-requirements-for-making-new-cryptocurrency-sites/364294#comment1216097_364294), @Catija♦ mentions that it'd require SE team bandwidth that likely isn't available right now, and that they'd need to coordinate with engineering/ dev team to find out how to make it happen. I'm pretty sure merges have occurred in the past, just on much smaller scales than with the crypto SE's.